# Getting date values for asp.net Online

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to get day-date values to list out news for each day. I used the following to get each day's day value :

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
string datecheck = myDateTime.Day.ToString();
```

and use datecheck to search news on that day.
It was correct in my localhost but after i upload it online. I think the DateTime.Now is not working. Please help. My code is asp.net (C#)

the code goes like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string datecheck = myDateTime.Day.ToString();
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            SqlCommand selectreport = new SqlCommand("select * from PowerNews", cnn);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = selectreport.ExecuteReader();
            put = new StringBuilder();
            _id.Clear();
            _content.Clear();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (dr["PowerNews_postDate"].ToString().Substring(0, 2) == datecheck)
                {
                    _id.Add(dr["PowerNews_Id"].ToString());
                    _content.Add(dr["PowerNews_content"].ToString());
                }
            }
            dr.Close();
.
.
.}
```

Comment: why is it not working? can you provide more clarifications on whats happening with your program

Comment: by not working, do you mean the server time is different from what you expect? the server might be in a different time zone.

Comment: if the culture is different from localhost it may never match powernews_postdate.substring == checkdate. have a look at checkdate on the server, and compare it with whats inside the database.